# AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'pushbutton_2'

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from Shifr import Ui_MainWindow


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def bp():
    ui.lineEdit.setText("22")

ui.pushbutton_2.clicked.connect(bp)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

вот сам код интерфейса

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(930, 608)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 887, 411))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_11, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 10, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 9, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 10, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 1, 6, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 8, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 10, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 7, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 1, 5, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_9 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_12 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_12, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_13, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_14, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_15 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_15, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_16 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_16.setObjectName("pushButton_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_16, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_17 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_17.setObjectName("pushButton_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_17, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_18 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_18.setObjectName("pushButton_18")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_18, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_19 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_19.setObjectName("pushButton_19")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_19, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_20 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_20.setObjectName("pushButton_20")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_20, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_21 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_21.setObjectName("pushButton_21")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_21, 0, 7, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_22 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_22.setObjectName("pushButton_22")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_22, 0, 8, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_23 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_23.setObjectName("pushButton_23")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_23, 0, 9, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_24 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_24.setObjectName("pushButton_24")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_24, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_25 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_25.setObjectName("pushButton_25")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_25, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_26 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_26.setObjectName("pushButton_26")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_26, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_27 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_27.setObjectName("pushButton_27")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_27, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_28 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_28.setObjectName("pushButton_28")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_28, 2, 4, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_29 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_29.setObjectName("pushButton_29")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_29, 2, 5, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_30 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_30.setObjectName("pushButton_30")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_30, 2, 6, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_31 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_31.setObjectName("pushButton_31")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_31, 2, 7, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_32 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_32.setObjectName("pushButton_32")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_32, 2, 8, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_33 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_33.setObjectName("pushButton_33")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_33, 2, 9, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(122, 60, 701, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 930, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "м", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ф", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "у", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "й", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "р", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "т", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "я", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "с", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "п", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "о", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "н", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "л", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "к", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "а", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "б", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_16.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "в", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_17.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "г", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_18.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "д", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_19.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "е", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_20.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ё", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_21.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ж", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_22.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "з", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_23.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "и", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_24.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "х", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_25.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ц", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_26.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ч", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_27.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ш", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_28.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "щ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_29.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ъ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_30.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ы", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_31.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ь", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_32.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "э", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_33.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "ю", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: замените `ui.pushbutton_2.clicked.connect(bp)`  на  `ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(bp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете push**b**utton_2, а в интерфейсе у вас push**B**utton_2.

в Python очень важен регистр.

Comment: Большое спасибо, такая глупая ошибка, просто только начал учить python